# Add animation to scrolling down to a specific div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello there i'm using the following code to scroll to the bottom at a specific div, and its working fine but, its too speedy, i want it to scroll slowly to the specific element, i know i can do it with jquery and i've been trying different codes for hours now, can anybody please help me with respect to my code, Thankyou.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cat-anchor").click(function(){
    $('html','body').animate({scrollTop: $(".cat-title").offset.top},'slow');
});
});
</script>

<div class="bran-cat">
        <h2>Category</h2>
        <div class="cat-list">
            <?php
                foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $cat_name){
                    echo "<a class='cat-anchor'>".">".$cat_name[1]."</a> <br>";
                }
                //$sel_cat= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ");
            ?>
        </div>
</div>
<?php

    foreach($cat_arr['cat_pro'] as $mykey=>$myvalues){
       echo '<div name="'.$myvalues[1].'" class="cat-title" id="'.$myvalues[0].'"><h2>'.$myvalues[1].'</h2></div>';
?>
```

Comment: I can't see related tags code in the posted one.......:(

Comment: where are your jquery code for scrolling?

Comment: on what event you want to scroll

Comment: Sorry i posted the old version by mistake, here is the latest version of my code, So sorry for that

Comment: @YoYo i want scrolling when we click anchor tag with class cat-anchor

Answer (score 3):

To scroll to specified element use jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$('body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#target-element').offset().top
}, 500);
```

Last argument is duration of animation.

Comment: Yeah its not working i applied the same code an hour ago, but it didn't work, let me share that

Comment: nice answer dude...!